# How to simulate a discrete ODE in MATLAB with adaptive step size?

Tags: matlab, dynamic, simulation, ode, discrete-mathematics

I have a discrete ODE, where `u` is the input and `y` is the output and `dy` is the derivative of `y`.

```
dy = @(y, u) 229.888852 - 0.050251*y + 3.116311*u + 0.000075 * y^2
```

I want to simulate this system with a ODE-solver e.g `ODE45`. But ODE45 requries a time vector `t` e.g

```
tspan = [0 5];
y0 = 0;
[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y) 2*t, tspan, y0);
```

And I don't have the `t` in my discrete ODE. I found it difficult to use ODE45 or other ODE-solvers in MATLAB / Octave because they don't handle discrete ODE's.

**My question is simple:**

How to simulate a discrete ODE in MATLAB with adaptive step size?

Comment: Can you clarify for the non-mathematicians what a "discrete ODE" is? Why is your equation not just an ODE?

Comment: Note also "t" as "time" is just a notation artifacts. An ODE is `dy=f(t,y)`, in your case it just seems that the common variable `t` is called `u`, but its the same thing. It does not need to represent time. Apologies if this exaplanation is trivial, but I am not sure what you are asking, so I explained just in case. The "time vector" in this case is just the boundaries of the equation.

Comment: @AnderBiguri This ODE is made by discrete data. Therefore it's a discrede ODE and not time continous.

Comment: @AnderBiguri So if I can use ODE45. How can I write it so I simulate it?

Comment: by replacing `@(t,y) 2*t` with `dy` in your code? Note the order of the inputs, though.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Sorry. I cannot understand. It does not even work `[t, y] = ode45(dy, [0, 20], 20);`

Comment: @AnderBiguri The simulation just blow up

Comment: Yes, indeed it does blow up. May be your equation/values, not an expert. Different initial values and ranges won't blow up.

Comment: @AnderBiguri So let's do a simple example. If I have a function `f(y, u) = y + u` and I want to simulate it in ODE45 and u is a constant value. How sould I wrote the ode funktion then? `[t, y] = ode45[f, [0 1], y0)` ? Where `y0` is the initial value of `y` argument? What about `u` argument?

Comment: if `u` is a constant value (e.g. `u=1`), your function is `val=1; f=@(u,y)y+val`

Comment: @AnderBiguri So the first argument, must be the `time` vector?

Comment: Please, do read the documentation, as I am answering by giving you the information there.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes. But this is so confusing `[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y) 2*t, tspan, y0);` Why `@(t, y)` when the equation is only `2t` ?

Comment: because `ode45` is a general method that requires all input functions to have those inputs in that order.

Comment: @AnderBiguri No it does't. I can simulate without the `t`

Comment: OK? It seems that you are arguing for the sake of arguing then... Anyway, I still don't know what your question is. Good luck, I obviously don't have the expertise to help you.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I just wonder how I can simulate my `dy` equation in ODE45.

Comment: You want to compute a function `y(t)` that has a differential equation `y'(t)=f(t,y(t),u(t))` where the control input `u(t)` is given as a function table for a piecewise constant or linear function?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes. I found an example here how to do a good simulation with ODE45 with control input. https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/265872-computing-state-space-equation-using-ode45-solver

Comment: the code is quite messy, but I will try to fix it. But the code works.